# App Inventor WebViewer history

Tags: android, webview, app-inventor

I'm trying to create an app using MIT's App Inventor. I'd need to get a history of the pages a user visits using a WebViewer block or, at least, count the number of pages visited. Note that I want to include the pages opened by links internal to the WebViewer.

I've been trying, but it looks like there is no possibility to detect any clicked link within the WebViewer. Maybe there is some way to detect and count URL changes?

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a `clock` component and a `list`.

Inside the `clock.timer` event check, if the `current url` is already stored in the `list`. If yes: do nothing else store the `current url` in the `list`